# is need to add restore button in all purchase screens

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

hello friends,
             In my game user can able to unlock the levels in 4 screens like (Title,level select, option, and end of free levels)... but i added restore button only one place in Title Screen. is it need to add restore button in all four screens...

my issue is my designers already designed UI. so if i add it not looking good. shall i add it on alert view. if user click unlock levels so i asked if already purchase, then user click "restore" button on alert view, else user click on "purchase it" button.

if apple approved my game... please any one clarify me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With non-consumable items ,you may not have a "restore button" but you must have a restore function. My app has no restore button , but has a restore function , and it also approved by apple. But it is better to has a restore function for non-consumable items. And you must has a restore function

Comment: hi kal, my game is non-consumable... i have restore function.if i dont add restore button then when i call restore functionality...

Comment: you can first check for if user has purchased or not if not then go for purchase  else restore his previous purchased items

Comment: oh... ok so if user clicked unlock levels first call this method  - (IBAction)restoreCompletedTransactions:(id)sender
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be necessary to have a button for that in multiple views.
Typically an app needs just one place for a function to restore purchases, since a user wants to restore (all) purchases at once.
So, unless you have specific/different requirements, adding this button in the titlescreen (or a settings screen if applicable) should be enough.